# Background Process in applet

Tags: java, applet

I am developing an applet and I want to do something that when I click a submit button then if a background process in running then it should indicate that a process is running in background and unable to do anything else.

I have tried something like progress bar but it needs to have coding in threads.
I am new in Java, so is there any other way to do this or I have to do it with the help of threads only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey frnd use Java swingworker class 
write your whole background BL in **doinbackground()** method .

Answer (score 1):

Like it or not, you'll have to get used to working with threads, since it is the only way to get a GUI element to update while the app. is doing processing.

But no need to panic, Java has some handy classes that handle most of the thread management for you.  See particularly the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for this.
some thing like :

```
  JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar(0, 20);
  pb.setValue(0);
  pb.setStringPainted(true);
```

For more details :

[Reference](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/SwingProgressBar.shtml)

Also [ProgressMonitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) may be the good option.